# Is there any way to resolve validating error when exporting data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, export-to-csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJVPM.jpg)

> Validating (Error)
> Messages
> Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task 1: The code page on Destination - binary_patient_2_txt.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[patient_id] is 949 and is required to be 1252.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - binary_patient_2_txt" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I keep getting this validation error when I tried to export my data from SQL Server.
Is there any way to resolve this issue by any chance?

Comment: SSIS doesn't do implicit conversion. Your column appears to be in a different code page to that of the file. Is your file in ANSI-1252 or is it in something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the Import / Export Wizard in SSMS, which opens up when you right click and choose Tasks > Export Data.

In this case, when you configure the flat file destination, change the collation to 949 - ANSI Korean (the default is 1252).  You may also need to check the unicode box depending on the source, but I would test without it first:

[image]

Comment: It works without getting the same error message. Thanks a lot!